# Add WMTS layers to OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, wmts

I have an OpenLayers  map with EPSG:3857 projection. I would like to add WMTS layer http://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/WMTS/guest/wmts/ORTO which support only matrix for EPSG:2180 and 4326.

Is any way to reproject this WMTS layer?

I was trying with this code but the layer is shown in wrong place.

```
    var WMTS2 = new ol.layer.Tile({
                    opacity: 0.5,
                    extent: projectionExtent,
                    source: new ol.source.WMTS({
                        url: 'http://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/WMTS/guest/wmts/ORTO',
                        layer: 'ORTOFOTOMAPA',
                        matrixSet: '2180',
                        format: 'image/jpeg',
                        projection: 'EPSG:2180',
                        tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.WMTS({
                            origin: ol.extent.getTopLeft(projectionExtent),
                            resolutions: resolutions,
                            matrixIds: matrixIds
                        }),
                        extent: projectionExtent,
                        style: 'default'
                    })
                });
```

Comment: You might have a go looking here [Openlayers site](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/raster-reprojection.html)

Comment: I used this metod above, but I don't know how Matrix reproject. The layers is placed in a wrong place on map.

Answer (score 3):

I tried setting that up using `ol.source.WMTS.optionsFromCapabilities` but it didn't work because the GetCapabilities lists the TopLeftCorner as `850000.0 100000.0` which is somewhere in Ukraine.  However I suspected the x and y were reversed and used the matrixIds, resolutions and tileSize returned by optionsFromCapabilities but changed the `origin: [850000, 100000]` to `[100000, 850000]` and it worked:

```
              tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.WMTS({
                  origin: [100000, 850000],
                  matrixIds: ["EPSG:2180:0",
                              "EPSG:2180:1",
                              "EPSG:2180:2",
                              "EPSG:2180:3",
                              "EPSG:2180:4",
                              "EPSG:2180:5",
                              "EPSG:2180:6",
                              "EPSG:2180:7",
                              "EPSG:2180:8",
                              "EPSG:2180:9",
                              "EPSG:2180:10",
                              "EPSG:2180:11",
                              "EPSG:2180:12",
                              "EPSG:2180:13"],
                 resolutions: [2116.6709,
                               1058.33545,
                                529.167725,
                                264.5838625,
                                132.29193125,
                                 66.145965625,
                                 26.458386249999997,
                                 13.229193124999998,
                                  6.614596562499999,
                                  2.645838625,
                                  1.3229193125,
                                  0.529167725,
                                  0.2645838625,
                                  0.13229193125],
                 tileSize: 512
              })
```

[image]

Comment: The service works fine for me in QGIS using either EPSG:2180 or EPSG:4326, so it doesn't look like coordinates are flipped.  For EPSG:2180 x axis is Northing (https://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::2180) and for EPSG:4326 x axis is latitiude (https://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326)

Comment: Those definitions won't work with OpenLayers.  In OpenLayers EPSG:4326 is predefined as LonLat, all other projections except EPSG:3857 require proj4 and are x, y unless the proj4 definition specifies "+axis=neu", which it doesn't https://epsg.io/2180.  Depending on your opinion either OpenLayers, the proj4 definition, or the WMTS service are incompatible.  There are similar issues with EPSG:31254.

Comment: OpenLayers has it wrong then.  OpenLayers can't define the axes order for EPSG projections, only EPSG can do that.

Comment: epsg.io is not the official registry of EPSG codes, you can't use it as the definitive source of axes order, you have to go to http://epsg-registry.org/

Comment: Most OpenLayers users wouldn't know about epsg-registry.org because they don't usually create their own proj4 definitions, they obtain them from sources such as epsg.io and spatialreference.org (neither specify +axis=neu in the proj4 definitions of EPSG:2180 and EPSG:31254, and only spatialreference.org specifies the axes in WKT) without needing to understand the syntax.  While users with sufficient knowledge of proj4 could update the definition, for most it would be easier to stick to using x, y coordinates throughout.

Comment: All that might be true, but the answer to this question cannot be that the WMTS service has incorrect coordinates, but rather that OL doesn't honour the correct axes order

Comment: Now I have seen the correct WKT for 2180 it's clear the WMTS service isn't incorrect, but it inconsistent with OpenLayers.  Somewhere in the code will be a proj4 definition string which defaults to enu so OL does honour the correct axes order which it has been given, so neither is OpenLayers incorrect there.   Either the proj4 definition needs to be updated, or the matrix origin needs to be specified in the x, y format.  In this case option 2 was easier..

Comment: Although not directly related to this question OpenLayers has consistently used its own definition of EPSG:4326 for over 10 years, that's not a problem for regular OpenLayers users, only for users switching between platforms