# Add NEW WMTS from geoportal.gov.pl in OpenLayers v3.9.0?

Tags: openlayers

i try to add New wmts raster service  from geoportal.gov.pl

https://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/PZGIK/ORTO/WMTS/StandardResolution?version=1.3.1&SERVICE=WMTS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities.

or

https://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/PZGIK/ORTO/WMTS/StandardResolution?version=1.1.1&SERVICE=WMTS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

Now i use old version (code).

How can i use new service. how to set new  **resolutions** from new?

```
//old version 
//copy from  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/293636/add-wmts-layers-to-openlayers

var myLayer= new ol.layer.Tile({
                opacity: 1,
                name: "" + array_params.layer_name + "_" + array_params.layer_index + "",
                source: new ol.source.WMTS({
                  url: 'https://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/WMTS/guest/wmts/ORTO',
                  layer: 'ORTOFOTOMAPA',
                  matrixSet: 'EPSG:2180',
                  format: 'image/jpeg',
                  projection: new ol.proj.Projection({
                    code: "EPSG:2180",
                    units: "m",
                    extent: [144907.16581514146, 129171.69217334315, 890379.1658151413, 812697.4119729949]
                  }),
                  tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.WMTS({
                    origin: [100000, 850000],
                    matrixIds: ["EPSG:2180:0",
                      "EPSG:2180:1",
                      "EPSG:2180:2",
                      "EPSG:2180:3",
                      "EPSG:2180:4",
                      "EPSG:2180:5",
                      "EPSG:2180:6",
                      "EPSG:2180:7",
                      "EPSG:2180:8",
                      "EPSG:2180:9",
                      "EPSG:2180:10",
                      "EPSG:2180:11",
                      "EPSG:2180:12",
                      "EPSG:2180:13"],
                    resolutions: [2116.6709,
                      1058.33545,
                      529.167725,
                      264.5838625,
                      132.29193125,
                      66.145965625,
                      26.458386249999997,
                      13.229193124999998,
                      6.614596562499999,
                      2.645838625,
                      1.3229193125,
                      0.529167725,
                      0.2645838625,
                      0.13229193125],
                    tileSize: 512
                  }),
                  style: 'default',
                  wrapX: true
                })
              });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you compare the old service http://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/WMTS/guest/wmts/ORTO?version=1.3.1&SERVICE=WMTS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

```
<TileMatrix>
<ows:Identifier>EPSG:2180:0</ows:Identifier>
<ScaleDenominator>7559538.928571429</ScaleDenominator>
<TopLeftCorner>850000.0 100000.0</TopLeftCorner>
<TileWidth>512</TileWidth>
<TileHeight>512</TileHeight>
<MatrixWidth>1</MatrixWidth>
<MatrixHeight>1</MatrixHeight>
</TileMatrix>

<TileMatrix>
<ows:Identifier>EPSG:2180:13</ows:Identifier>
<ScaleDenominator>472.4711830357143</ScaleDenominator>
<TopLeftCorner>850000.0 100000.0</TopLeftCorner>
<TileWidth>512</TileWidth>
<TileHeight>512</TileHeight>
<MatrixWidth>11369</MatrixWidth>
<MatrixHeight>10704</MatrixHeight>
</TileMatrix>
<TileMatrix>
<ows:Identifier>EPSG:2180:14</ows:Identifier>
<ScaleDenominator>236.23559151785716</ScaleDenominator>
<TopLeftCorner>850000.0 100000.0</TopLeftCorner>
<TileWidth>512</TileWidth>
<TileHeight>512</TileHeight>
<MatrixWidth>22737</MatrixWidth>
<MatrixHeight>21408</MatrixHeight>
</TileMatrix>
```

and the new service https://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/PZGIK/ORTO/WMTS/StandardResolution?version=1.3.1&SERVICE=WMTS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

```
<TileMatrix>
<ows:Identifier>EPSG:2180:0</ows:Identifier>
<ScaleDenominator>3.0238155714285716E7</ScaleDenominator>
<TopLeftCorner>850000.0 100000.0</TopLeftCorner>
<TileWidth>512</TileWidth>
<TileHeight>512</TileHeight>
<MatrixWidth>1</MatrixWidth>
<MatrixHeight>1</MatrixHeight>
</TileMatrix>
<TileMatrix>
<ows:Identifier>EPSG:2180:1</ows:Identifier>
<ScaleDenominator>1.5119077857142858E7</ScaleDenominator>
<TopLeftCorner>850000.0 100000.0</TopLeftCorner>
<TileWidth>512</TileWidth>
<TileHeight>512</TileHeight>
<MatrixWidth>1</MatrixWidth>
<MatrixHeight>1</MatrixHeight>
</TileMatrix>
<TileMatrix>
<ows:Identifier>EPSG:2180:2</ows:Identifier>
<ScaleDenominator>7559538.928571429</ScaleDenominator>
<TopLeftCorner>850000.0 100000.0</TopLeftCorner>
<TileWidth>512</TileWidth>
<TileHeight>512</TileHeight>
<MatrixWidth>1</MatrixWidth>
<MatrixHeight>1</MatrixHeight>
</TileMatrix>

<ows:Identifier>EPSG:2180:15</ows:Identifier>
<ScaleDenominator>472.4711830357143</ScaleDenominator>
<TopLeftCorner>850000.0 100000.0</TopLeftCorner>
<TileWidth>512</TileWidth>
<TileHeight>512</TileHeight>
<MatrixWidth>11323</MatrixWidth>
<MatrixHeight>10656</MatrixHeight>
</TileMatrix>
<TileMatrix>
<ows:Identifier>EPSG:2180:16</ows:Identifier>
<ScaleDenominator>236.23559151785716</ScaleDenominator>
<TopLeftCorner>850000.0 100000.0</TopLeftCorner>
<TileWidth>512</TileWidth>
<TileHeight>512</TileHeight>
<MatrixWidth>22645</MatrixWidth>
<MatrixHeight>21312</MatrixHeight>
</TileMatrix>
</TileMatrixSet>
```

You will see the previous level 0 `ScaleDenominator` is the same as the new level 2, with two new entries inserted at the top and all other values moved down (including a level 14 - now 16 - which was not used the the previous example).

So the new tilegrid settings will be

```
                  matrixIds: ["EPSG:2180:0",
                              "EPSG:2180:1",
                              "EPSG:2180:2",
                              "EPSG:2180:3",
                              "EPSG:2180:4",
                              "EPSG:2180:5",
                              "EPSG:2180:6",
                              "EPSG:2180:7",
                              "EPSG:2180:8",
                              "EPSG:2180:9",
                              "EPSG:2180:10",
                              "EPSG:2180:11",
                              "EPSG:2180:12",
                              "EPSG:2180:13",
                              "EPSG:2180:14",
                              "EPSG:2180:15",
                              "EPSG:2180:16"],
                 resolutions: [2116.6709 * 4,
                               2116.6709 * 2,
                               2116.6709,
                               1058.33545,
                                529.167725,
                                264.5838625,
                                132.29193125,
                                 66.145965625,
                                 26.458386249999997,
                                 13.229193124999998,
                                  6.614596562499999,
                                  2.645838625,
                                  1.3229193125,
                                  0.529167725,
                                  0.2645838625,
                                  0.13229193125,
                                  0.13229193125 / 2],
```